# Rails 5 install error (DEPRECATION WARNING: alias_method_chain is deprecated)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

I'm running into this error after installing rails 5.0.0 on my project. I'm starting to think it's Devise gem or something. I tried multiple ways, but can't seem to figure it out. 
I've tried this for devise gem, but same result.

> gem 'devise', :github => 'plataformatec/devise', :branch => 'master'

```
DEPRECATION WARNING: alias_method_chain is deprecated. Please, use Module#prepend instead. From module, you can access the original method using super. (called from <top (required)> at /home/nitrous/code/uvesty/config/environment.rb:5)
Exiting
/home/nitrous/code/uvesty/.bundle/gems/actionpack-5.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/stack.rb:108:in `assert_index': No such middleware to insert after: ActionDispatch::ParamsParser (RuntimeError
```

I also thought I might need to change all my

```
@user = User.find(params[:id])
```

to

```
@user = User.find_by(id: params[:id])
```

Comment: may be it will help you https://github.com/lassebunk/gretel/issues/65

Comment: The alias method chain bit appears to be a warning, the hard error is the but below about ActuonDispatch::ParamsParser. What makes you think devise is the problem?

Comment: I was getting some responses online saying it MAY be devise. But i just tried it without devise, and it's the same error. And you're right! It's just a WARNING, so it shouldn't make my project crash. That means my rails server isn't running because of the second line of error...which i'm stuck still in.

Answer (score 0):

First change devise declaration in **Gemfile** like

```
gem "devise", '~> 4.0.0.rc1'
```

Secondly, you **don't need** to change this line, as find method is **NOT** deprecated.

```
@user = User.find(params[:id])
```

Please check [what new in rails 5](http://blog.michelada.io/whats-new-in-rails-5)

Comment: Unfortunately, that didn't fix the problem. Same error

Comment: Why that pre-release version of devise instead of the newer 4.2.0?

Comment: Yeah, not sure. but i got the newest 4.2.0 and it works fine. The issue was a gem (rails_admin). There's actually an article on how to fix it if anyone cares. I haven't tried it. http://dev.mensfeld.pl/2015/12/upgrading-to-ruby-on-rails-5-0-from-rails-4-2-application-use-case/

Answer (score 0):

The issue was the gem rails_admin. I removed it and it's all fine now. It seems they might have not updated their gem for rails 5.0.